# FriendFeed backdating feeds?

Tags: rss, friendfeed

I have just created a FriendFeed account for the following:

- Twitter
- Facebook
- Delicious
- Wordpress RSS feed 1
- Wordpress RSS feed 2

These are all personal things that I want stored in a single place.

FF has only imported 60 items.

Is this normal and is there a way to make it backdate all the way to the beginning of my Facebook / Twitter account etc? (There is a large amount of data altogether.)

Comment: (for information, you can use " - " for lists, or simply two spaces at the end of a line for a break line.)

Comment: It wasn't particularly necessary to add an unordered list, an answer would have been more helpful, but thanks nether the less.

Comment: it was only that you wrote a list, and it didn't render as such. This is why I was giving a formatting tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS feeds are meant to be used to follow news, so it will give you the latest updates. It is meant to be checked quite often.

In this approach, there is no need to provide RSS "file" with a list of all items since the beginning, it's not the goal of it. This is why most RSS feeds contain only a fixed number of latest elements. Since a RSS feed is simply an XML file provided by the sites, they don't have interest in having it contain all data since the beginning, as it would be too voluminous, especially to check often.

So to answer you, this is why most of your RSS will miss the first elements. And Friendfeed can't do something about it.

It could be different for the ones accessed via some API (like maybe Twitter and Facebook, I don't know), maybe these ones could give you the totality of updates.

But my guess is that Friendfeed's purpose is to centralize updates from different services. As such, only the most recent are necessary, no need for them to import the whole archive. I don't think there is any setting in FF for that. At least I have not found one.

Comment: Good point, I didn't even think about RSS having a limit, which is obvious. Thanks.